# Celerybeat Multiple schedules of the same task

Tags: django, cron, celery, django-celery

I got following Celery beat task which cleans 1000 items daily at 1 AM:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
from .celery import app as celery_app

celery_app.conf.beat_schedule['maintenance'] = {
        'task': 'my_app.tasks.maintenance',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=1, minute=0),
        'args': (1000,)
    }
```

I want to clean additional 5000 items every Sunday at 5PM. Is there a way to add second schedule?

```
        'schedule': crontab(hour=17, minute=0, day_of_week='sunday'),
        'args': (5000,)
```

And how to ensure they won't overlap?

Comment: which means sunday second schedule should work and remaining day first schedule should work?

Comment: Yes. Originally I considered 2 maintenances to trigger on Sunday. But maybe it's simpler to just launch one big on Sunday with different schedule name. This will solve both: 2 schedules and overlap.

Comment: So you got your answer

Answer (score -1):

Task1 will run every day including sunday and Task 2 will run only on sunday

```
  app.conf.beat_schedule = {
        'task1':{
            'task':'my_app.tasks.maintenance',
            'schedule': crontab(hour=1, minute=0),
            'args': (1000,)
        },
        'task2':{
            'task':'my_app.tasks.maintenance',
            'schedule': crontab(minute=00, hour=17, day_of_week='sunday'),
            'args': (5000,)
        },
   }
```

Comment: This will not work. I ran into this problem myself. Because they are the same task, the 2nd will overwrite the first inside celery. Someone else explained: "task_name is a unique index. In table periodictask, a task-name can be there only once."